# How to check if a string is in datetime format in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

Edit: Is it possible to check if the string is in a certain format such as 'y-m-d','h:m:s'

Comment: run `str()` to see the structure of the object.

Comment: I can't seem to find the documentation on str(). But if I put a string within the str() it would just be chr in R, it doesn't check anything beyond that. @Phil

Comment: you should provide few examples of how you expect the function to behave. It would be even better if you show us that you have tried something that didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lubridate::is.timepoint(Sys.time())
#> TRUE
lubridate::is.timepoint(Sys.Date())
#> TRUE
```

From the documentation of `?lubridate::is.timepoint`:

> TRUE if x is a POSIXct, POSIXlt, or Date object, FALSE otherwise.

---

If you want to identify only datetimes and not dates:

```
lubridate::is.POSIXt(Sys.time())
#> TRUE
lubridate::is.POSIXt(Sys.Date())
#> FALSE
```

---

EDIT.

If you want to check a specific format you can try to read it with that format, if you get NA, then it is not.

For example:

```
is.ymd_hms <- function(x) !is.na(lubridate::ymd_hms(x, quiet = TRUE))

is.ymd_hms("2020-01-01 22:22:22")
#> TRUE
is.ymd_hms("2020-31-01 22:22:22")
#> FALSE
```

Without lubridate:

```
is.ymd_hms2 <- function(x) !is.na(as.Date(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

is.ymd_hms2("2020-01-01 22:22:22")
#> TRUE
is.ymd_hms2("2020-31-01 22:22:22")
#> FALSE
```

However, lubridate gives you more flexibility. Like:

```
is.ymd_hms("2020/01/01 22:22:22")
#> TRUE
is.ymd_hms2("2020/01/01 22:22:22")
#> FALSE
```

Comment: Then is it possible to check if the string is in a certain format such as 'y-m-d','h:m:s'

Comment: look at my edit